# AJAX search box in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some trouble getting my AJAX request to work in my MVC project.

At the moment, the search function works correctly - I'm getting the expected results from my data. But when the submit button is pressed the browser is redirected to "SearchPhilosophers" view - call the method of the same name. But I don't understand why this is happening because that method is declared to only return a partial view.

Here's the method inside PhilosophersController.cs:

```
    public PartialViewResult SearchPhilosophers (string keyword)
    {
        var data = db.Philosophers.Where(p =>p.LastName.StartsWith(keyword)).ToList();
        return PartialView(data);
    }
```

Here's the index view file:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MVCPhilosopher.Models.Philosopher>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "searchResult",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    };
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach (var philosopher in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = philosopher.Id })">
                <img src="/Images/@philosopher.ImgFile"
                     alt="@philosopher.FullName"
                     class="img-responsive" height="400" width="160"/>
            </a>
            <h3>@Html.ActionLink(philosopher.FullName, "Details",
                   new { id = @philosopher.Id })</h3>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody id="searchResult">
        @Html.Action("SearchPhilosophers", new { keyword = "" })
    </tbody>
</table>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchPhilosophers", options))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("keyword", null, new {id = "Search"})
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}
```

The SearchPhilosphers partial view is very simple:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCPhilosopher.Models.Philosopher>

@foreach(var p in Model)
{
    <h2>@p.LastName</h2>
}
```

Please can someone explain my a new page is being requested and the AJAX request isn't working on the same page?

Comment: you have installed the plugin  `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`??

Comment: and you have to provide `InsertionMode` and `UpdateTargetId` for `AjaxOptions` in `Ajax.BeginForm` ..

Comment: If your submit button is redirecting rather than updating the same page, it means you have not loaded `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in the main view or its layout

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were right, I hadn't referenced the Ajax script in the layout file!